# How to checkout a specific repo tag?

Tags: databricks, databricks-repos

I've created a repo in Databricks. I would like to work on a specific tagged version of the repo, however, I can't see options in the UI to specify the branch.

Next I created a notebook and attempted to run

```bash
%sh git tag
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Is it possible to switch to a tag, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out a specific tag with [Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/repos-cli.html#update-a-repo-to-the-most-recent-commit-of-a-remote-branch-or-to-a-tag):

```
$ databricks repos create --url https://github.com/databricks-academy/data-engineering-with-databricks.git --path /Repos/u/Academy
{
  "id": 3965682671931295,
  "path": "/Repos/u/Academy",
  "url": "https://github.com/databricks-academy/data-engineering-with-databricks.git",
  "provider": "gitHub",
  "branch": "published",
  "head_commit_id": "6c3b171726803c1bb7494ed592ae549dcafa1f81"
}

$ databricks repos update --repo-id 3965682671931295 --tag v2.2.2
{
  "id": 3965682671931295,
  "url": "https://github.com/databricks-academy/data-engineering-with-databricks.git",
  "provider": "gitHub",
  "head_commit_id": "619532eddf7d2cce8f48772afc8d69797036890c"
}
```